# How to apply a Word Quick Style in C# - not just simple formatting but the entire style?

Tags: c#, interop, ms-word, styling

I admit, I am very new to using the Interop libraries, but the advice people always seem to give is, record a macro and check out the vba code. The problem is, the macro does not record exactly what I am doing: *Clicking a Quick Style to apply it to the current selection*.

My task is pretty simple: **I need to apply a Quick Style to a Paragraph (*Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph*)**. Using the *set_style* command however, only applies basic formatting, and the paragraph keeps it original Quick Style selection (*Normal*).

Using Remou's approach it worked for me though, but it seems very similar to my own code, and I can not make it work, and I think it might be my understanding of the objectmodel that is a bit off.

```
public void AddParagraph(string text, string styleName = null)
{
  Paragraph paragraph = _document.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
  if (styleName != null)
  {
    paragraph.Range.set_Style(_document.Styles[styleName]);
  }

  paragraph.Range.Text = text;
  paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
}
```

I then call it with e.g. `AddParagraph("A title", "Heading 1");`, but the result of using the above wrapper to build my document is, that no complete styles are applied, only font, color, size and bold/italics.

I am using my own `.dotx` file, with my own defined and named styles, but simply copying the code from Remou works with my own template, so I do not think that is the issue, and using that code I am unable to figure out how to append multiple paragraphs with each their own styling.

Can anyone point out what is wrong with my approach, or at least how I can make the answer provided by Remou work for my requirements? :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me.

```
Word.Application _wordApp = new Word.Application();
Word.Document oDoc = _wordApp.Documents.Add();
_wordApp.Visible = true;
_wordApp.Selection.TypeText("Heading");
oDoc.Paragraphs[1].set_Style(Word.WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading2);
```

When you say

```
paragraph.Range.Text = text + paragraph.Range.Text;
```

You are getting more paragraphs than you imagined. I reckon you need:

```
paragraph.Range.Text = text;
```

Try:

```
Paragraph paragraph = _document.Content.Paragraphs.Add();
paragraph.Range.Text = text;

if (styleName != null)
{ 
    paragraph.set_Style(_document.Styles[styleName]);
}

paragraph.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

Comment: Thanks Remou, I've updated my question, as you got me a bit closer but not all the way. I am probably going about this a wrong way.

Comment: ... I'm dumbstruck. Changing the order of applying style and text is what did it, the ` + paragraph.Range.Text;` part was something old I attempted and copied by mistake. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

This took me a while to figure it out.
Well the below code works for me just fine.

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph paraTitle = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
            paraTitle.Range.Text = ""; //This line does the trick here
            paraTitle.Range.set_Style(WdBuiltinStyle.wdStyleHeading1);
            paraTitle.Range.Text = text;
```

This will apply the whole style and not just the formatting.