# write paragraphs with style into word document using C#

Tags: c#, interop, ms-word

I have been trying to print this text into Microsoft Word document file.

Items A :

- item1
- item2

Items B :

- item3
- item4

I have style "Body" for "Items A : " and "Items B : ";
and style "Bullet1" for the item list

I try many different things, but none has ever worked the way it should be.
This is one of the example:

```
object body = "Body";
object bullet1 = "Bullet1";

Word.Paragraph para2 = _wordDoc.Paragraphs.Add(Missing.Value);            
para2.Range.set_Style(body);
para2.Range.Text = "Items : ";
para2.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();

Word.Paragraph para = _wordDoc.Paragraphs.Add(Missing.Value);
string text = "Item1 \nItem2";
para.Range.Text = text;
para.Range.set_Style(bullet1);

Word.Paragraph para3 = _wordDoc.Paragraphs.Add(Missing.Value);
para3.Range.set_Style(body);
para3.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
```

Could you please tell me the mistakes on the code or any suggestion?
My hypothesis is there is something weird about set_style, but i cannot describe why.
Thank you.

Comment: What happens when that code example is run?  An error?  Badly-formatted text?

Comment: badly-formatted text. the bullets are not in the targetted lines, and the styles are messed up.

Comment: Does this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12190883/how-to-apply-a-word-quick-style-in-c-sharp-not-just-simple-formatting-but-the/12193834#12193834 ?

Comment: it does help. i might need to change some parts, but now i know more about style and adding paragraph.. thanks a lot!!